# How to fix "make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)" in react native expo-notifications?

Tags: javascript, react-native, notifications, expo

I've already tried everything, rebuilt the app for the 10th time and still nothing works, so I decided to write here.
I'm trying to get expo-notifications to work, but no matter what I change in app.json, how many times I delete and start a new firebase project I get the following error:

"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.sentakki. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.sentakki. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first."

Things I've done:
Installed expo-notifications and expo-device
Copied code from here, but the code doesn't matter, because even simple function like getExpoPushToken() fails, so it's not about the code
Created a firebase project, and followed every step in the official expo tutorial (enabling legacy messaging etc)
Copied google-services.json to the project directory
Included googleServicesFile in app.json and added expo-notifications in expo.plugins key
Built the development build via EAS build, and installed on real device
Configured expo credentials to work with firebase messaging

This is my app.json:

```
{   "expo": {     "name": "Sentakki mobile",     "slug": "sentakki-mobile",     "scheme": "com.sentakki",     "version": "1.0.0",     "orientation": "portrait",     "icon": "./assets/logo.png",     "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",     "splash": {       "image": "./assets/splash.png",       "resizeMode": "contain",       "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"     },     "updates": {       "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0     },     "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],     "ios": {       "supportsTablet": true     },     "android": {       "package": "com.sentakki",       "adaptiveIcon": {         "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",         "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"       },       "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",       "useNextNotificationsApi": true     },     "web": {       "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"     },     "extra": {       "eas": {         "projectId": "here is project id and it's accesible via expo-constants"       }     },     "plugins": [["expo-localization"], ["expo-notifications"]]   },   "build": {     "preview": {       "android": {         "buildType": "apk"       },     },   } }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.